# How I get notified every time their is an *new* update and not every day for the sames updates?

Tags: updating, security, users

The update module can send you email when a new release is available for a module you installed. The problem is I get a email everyday. Some security update are very minor and unreachable for an attacker, I don't want to update the website and so I don't want future notification about this update.

I would like to be notified every time their is an *new* update, not every day for the sames updates.

Comment: That'll need a core patch (to `update_requirements()` and `_update_cron_notify()` at least by the looks of things). It would be much easier to ignore the emails and check the site manually on a schedule that suits your workflow

Comment: This looks to me more of a feature request for the core update module, than a question. This should be discussed on a issue queue on drupal.org and not here.

Comment: Gmail is pretty good at hiding duplicated content in conversation, so I'm getting mails but see immediately if there's something new or not. On the other side, I don't ignore updates (I have the luxury of applying them as they go), so haven't tested with this particular mailing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use [hook_mail_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) to cancel the sending of the mail. I can simply store a md5 of the mail's body every time the mail is send and compare it with the "new" email, if it's the same I don't send it.

Comment: I'm not sure about the MD5 of the emails, but instead of using hook_form_alter, I'd suggest you to use the `hook_mail_alter()`, instead. you can do the check in that function and then set the argument of the function `$message['send']` to `FALSE` to stop the mail from being sent, based on the condition (MD5).

Comment: I said hook_mail_alter... edited my message to make a proper link.

Comment: Oh, my bad! Slip of sight I suppose ;-)